Import File Names Only of Google Folders in R
I have a folder in my Google drive containing multiple subfolders. All I want to do is create an R script that import the files names into a dataframe in R. Ideally I would also like to have the folder and sub-folder names in the dataframe but it's not a must. I'm not interested in the content of the files. I'm only interested in the names.
Thank you

Welcome to SO. In order to get help here, share an MRE of your code with the community. What have you tried? What error message did you get?

Read https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/drive_ls.html
